# TCL Expect Not Writing To Output Buffer

Tags: linux, expect, tcl

I have noticed that my TCL/Expect Script is not writing to the Output Buffer.

```
`#!/usr/bin/expect -f

exp_internal 1; #Debug Expect

set username [lindex $argv 0]; #Takes Outside Argument
set password [lindex $argv 1]; #Takes Outside Argument
set hostFile [open hosts.txt r]; #Reads from a local file


while { [gets $hostFile hostname] >= 0 } {
spawn ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $username@$hostname
expect "password: "

send  "$password\r"
expect "$ "

send "pbrun /bin/su -"
expect {
 "Operations Team.*" {
  puts "NewLine Was Caught After pbrun /bin/su - command"
  #break #Exit While loop, which will exit the server since there is only one While Loop aprund the whole SSH Session
 }
 "Rejected.*" {
  puts "NewLine & Return Carraige Was Caught After pbrun /bin/su - command"
  #break #Exit While loop, which will exit the server since there is only one While Loop aprund the whole SSH Session
 }
 #"^" { ;#This command will work because in the expect only picks up a    "^" character from the [send "pbrun /bin/su -"] command. This is an issues as the pbrun command has more ouput that just a "^", but expect only picks up the "^" character. You can use any other command like "ls", and expect does not write the ls command ouput to the buffer, only a newline character will be written to the buffer. This is an issue as I am unable to grab anything from expect.
 # puts "Newline Character Met"
 #}
}

send "hostname\r"
expect {
 -re {".{8}[0-9]{5}"} {; #Never Works
  puts "BUFFER:$expect_out(buffer):REFFUB"
 }
 "^" {; #Again, this will be met
  puts "Newline Character Met"
 }
}
}`
```

Any Help Is Much appreciated. I ran this in debug mode and indeed see that there is no output being written to the buffer for the `pbrun /bin/su -` or `hostname` command except for the `^` character.

Comment: you seem to be missing a `\r` at the end of `send "pbrun /bin/su -"`.

Answer (score 1):

Your actual problem: the pattern `{".{8}[0-9]{5}"}` will match a string containing a double quote followed by 8 characters followed by 5 digits followed by a double quote -- are those double quotes meant to be in your pattern? Sometimes people get confused by Tcl's quoting, so my question is not meant to carry any judgement with it.

Also, when you have 2 patterns in an expect block, any one can match first: are you expecting the 8 chars and 5 nums to be seen *before* the first newline?

Wait, `^` will match at the start of the first line. If you want to explicitly match a newline, use `\n`.

---

Unfortunately Tcl's comment handling can be confusing. The comment character `#` *only* starts a comment **if it is seen where a command can go**.

The comments you put inside your expect block **do not comment out those lines**.

```
expect {
 "Operations Team.*" {
  puts "NewLine Was Caught After pbrun /bin/su - command"
  #break #Exit While loop, which will exit the server since there is only one While Loop aprund the whole SSH Session
 }
 "Rejected.*" {
  puts "NewLine & Return Carraige Was Caught After pbrun /bin/su - command"
  #break #Exit While loop, which will exit the server since there is only one While Loop aprund the whole SSH Session
 }
 #"^" { ;#This command will work because in the expect only picks up a    "^" character from the [send "pbrun /bin/su -"] command. This is an issues as the pbrun command has more ouput that just a "^", but expect only picks up the "^" character. You can use any other command like "ls", and expect does not write the ls command ouput to the buffer, only a newline character will be written to the buffer. This is an issue as I am unable to grab anything from expect.
 # puts "Newline Character Met"
 #}
}
```

You are essentially passing to the `expect` command a list containing `pattern` and `action` pairs. The 3rd pattern is literally the 4 characters `#"^"` and the 3rd action is a string containing a script that contains 3 comments.

Comment: Hi Glen, Thanks For your quick response! the issue begins in the second send command `send "pbrun /bin/su -"`. See, my debug output looks like this in the second statement command `send: sending "pbrun /bin/su -" to { exp6 }

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "Rejected*"? no
"Operations Team*"? no
pbrun /bin/su -`. The first issue I see is that nothing is written to expects buffer right after executing the send command, which it should. So then expect decides to rexecute the second command. In the last send command, I removed the `""`, but the issue is the same as well.

Comment: By the issue being the same as well, I mean that expect does not write to the buffer, so only `""` is searched as the expect_out(buffer), instead of the actual output that my send commands triggered. So then expect times out on the `pbrun` command. Next is the `hostname` command. For some reason, expect compares the output of hostname to be `pbrun /bin/su -`, which is just weird. Finally, expect continues to send the `hostname` command with the `pbrun` command appended to it, and since one of the commands it sends is `pbrun /bin/su -hostname\r\n`, that incorrect command actually triggers an

Comment: error, which outputs a string that matches the pattern `.{8}[0-9]{5}`, so `puts "BUFFER:$expect_out(buffer):REFFUB"` is printed. The problem I am seeing is that expect is simply sending the `pbrun` without writing the first output to the buffer, which is where the problems arise since the expected ouput should be comapred against the preeceding `expect` statement, but none are met, because expect never wrote the output of the send command after executing". However, in the first `ssh` & `password` command, expect writes the output to it's buffer, so the proceeding expect statements are met.

Comment: You'll need to post the debugging output as a gist or pastebin or something. Did you notice meuh's comment about sending `\r`? That's like typing a command at the shell prompt and forgetting to hit Enter.

Comment: In fact, if that's the error, then the command you end up typing will be `pbrun /bin/su -hostname\r`. What happens if you do that "in real life"?

Comment: Also, the commands you send will show up in the buffer. For the exact same reason that characters you type are displayed in the terminal. If you don't want that, try `stty -echo`

Answer (score 0):

By default, pbrun runs in a terminal session. I am not a TCL expert, but when running pbrun via shell scripts, pbrun sometimes needs to be run in pipe mode when dealing with the output of pbun.

```
"pbrun -p <command> | /usr/local/bin/db_check.sh"
```

In addition, you may also want to use the -n (null input) when dealing with sending a pbrun command and there is no input via stdin but somehow pbrun gets some buffered data because the script calling pbrun is not clean.

```
   -n,  --null_input
          Redirects  the  standard input of pbrun to /dev/null.  You some‐
          times need this option to avoid interactions between  pbrun  and
          the  shell  that  invokes  it.   For example, if you are running
          pbrun and start a pbrun in the  background  without  redirecting
          its input away from the terminal, it will block even if no reads
          are posted by the remote command.   This  option  corrects  this
          situation.


   -p,  --pipe_mode
          Pipe mode. Forces the secured task to behave as if it is run  in
          a  pipeline  rather  than  a terminal session.  This option also
          suppresses utmp  entries,  so  that  the  session  will  not  be
          recorded as a login on the runhost.
```

Last item, "Rejected" messages are returned on stderr, not stdout.